# magento get value from sales_flat_order_item table for print in invoice page

Tags: magento

i am using magento 1.7.0.2.In sales_flat_order_item table i have created a field "real_original_price" where i storing product's original price(in case of special price).Price is storing properly.Now problem is how do i show the real_original_price field's data in my invoice page .Actually my target is showing user discounted amount in invoice that is (original price - sell price). How do i achieve this.any idea

https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/display-attributes-on-invoice-or-packing-slip-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

You can write an observer on order save or invoice save event. In the observer you can fetch the original price from catalog_product_entity and update in sales_flat_order.